# How to rotate an object around a point with GLM OpenGL C++?

Tags: c++, rotation, glm-math

I'm trying to do something like this, but for some reason my cube still rotates around the origin. What am I doing wrong?

```
glm::mat4 identity = glm::mat4(1.0f); // construct identity matrix

glm::mat4 trans;
glm::mat4 rot;
glm::mat4 transBack;
glm::mat4 M;

glm::vec4 br = glm::vec4(currentPositionX - 0.4, 0.0f, currentPositionZ + 1.2, 1.0f);

//get the matrix transformation to translate
trans = glm::translate(identity, glm::vec3(+0.4, 0.0f, -1.2));

identity = glm::mat4(1.0f); // construct identity matrix
//get the matrix transformation to rotate
rot = glm::rotate(identity, glm::radians(rotation), glm::vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0));  // rotate with car ROT -

identity = glm::mat4(1.0f); // construct identity matrix
//get the matrix transformation to translate
transBack = glm::translate(identity, glm::vec3(-0.4, 0.0f, +1.2));

M = transBack * rot * trans;

// A' = M . A , A being a point 
br = M * br;
```

Comment: Seems to me that you are already doing the translation manually in the coordinates of `br` and then reversing it with `trans`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formula to rotate a point around `(x,y,z)` is:

```
T(x,y,z) * R * T(-x,-y,-z)   // operations are combined from right to left
```

you have to move the point `P(x,y,z)` to center of locale coordinate system, apply rotate
and translate back to world space.

```
auto rotAroundPoint(float rad, const glm::vec3& point, const glm::vec3& axis)
{
auto t1 = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1),-point);
auto r = glm::rotate(glm::mat4(1),rad,axis);
auto t2 = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1),point);
return t2 * r * t1;
}

int main() {
glm::vec4 geom(0,0,0,1); // one point of cube geometry
glm::vec3 o(6,0,6); // origin of rotation
glm::vec3 cp(5,0,5); // current position of cube
for (float deg : {0.f,90.f,180.f,270.f}) {
    auto res = rotAroundPoint(glm::radians(deg),o,glm::vec3(0,1,0)) * 
        glm::translate(glm::mat4(1),cp) * geom;
    std::cout << glm::to_string(res) << std::endl;
}
/*
      ------------------> x
      |
      |
      |            cp(5,5)         (7,5)
      |                    o(6,6)
      |            (5,7)           (7,7)
      |
      z
*/
```

[godbolt demo](https://godbolt.org/z/jrj67Kx8q)